# Connect MC900 Mini CCTV camera via GPIO pins

Tags: gpio, camera

Is there anyway to connect wires from a camera to GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi to use/control the camera?

In my case this is the camera.
[image: MC900 Mini CCTV camera]

I to look something like this
[image: Wiring]

Comment: what are the pins labelled? I suspect VCC, GND and Composite?

Comment: pin1-dc5v pin2-gnd pin3-video out

Comment: Then the answer is you cannot do it. Get the Pi camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an analogue camera. The Raspberry Pi only has digital inputs. You will need to buy a USB Video grabber to convert the analogue signal into something the Raspberry Pi can process.

Comment: The control interface might be possible to use directly (it depends what it actually is) but the video interface is not.

Comment: So I can't connect it directly?

Comment: @kwasmich and sorry one more question can I use a 3.5 adapter instead of the usb [link](https://www.olx.ba/artikal/30222897/av-3-5mm-video-jack-to-3-rca-adapter-audio-cable/)

Comment: No, the 3.5 jack on the pi can only output audio and video.

Comment: @kwasmich thanks a lot, one last question: what do you think, because of arduino having an analogue inputs is it a good idea to connect this camera to arudino uno then stream the video to the pi and is it going to slow down the pi?
(I'm working on a python project with the opencv library so I need the video in the real time)

Comment: what would be the Arduino's function?

Comment: If you do some math, you will notice that the arduinos ADC is way to slow to process video in real time.

Comment: @jsotola I'm building a machine for counting coins(coin acceptor and sorter like ones in the coffee machines but with a camera and scale) so I'm using Arduino anyway and it has a lot of functions in my project, so, I'm wondering, instead of buying a USB video grabber, I can just connect the camera to the Arduino and not directly to the pi then send the stream from Arduino to my pi-python project-(the process speed isn't that important to me but sure don't want it to be that slow if You know what I mean :)).
hopefully that clarified the situation, if You have any suggestions please let me know

Comment: i do not think that the arduino is fast enough to process video ... you could post a question at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @kwasmich sorry for bothering You, how did You know this is an analogue camera because I saw in the specifications this detail:
IMAGE SIGNAL PROCESS- Digital Signal Processing System
can You explain please

Comment: The yellow RCA plug is a safe sign for that, along with the datasheet stating it supports NTSC and PAL signals. Both of which were analog.

Comment: Anyway. analog cameras are not bad per-se. They usually have lower latency than their digital counterparts. But at some point you will have to make the signal digital in order to process it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can attach a camera via the GPIO pins to a Raspberry PICO. I'm building a wildlife/trail camera, and am using the PICO instead of a full RPI single board computer.

Here is the link to the documentation which shows the cameras you need to use.

[SPI Camera for Raspberry PI PICO](https://www.arducam.com/docs/pico/arducam-camera-module-for-raspberry-pi-pico/spi-camera-for-raspberry-pi-pico/)

Answer (score 0):

If GPIO 3 failed then GPIO  4 or GPIO 16 are also usable. Make sure to use a ground and a electric input depending on the camera! I use 3+4 and the 3.4V +ground since my camera was a salvation from an old phone! Mostly these are around 3.5V!